# pymediainfoが利用できずエラーが発生する

Tags: python, windows

## 環境説明

pymediainfoはメディアファイル解析ツールであるmediainfoのpythonラッパーです。

Windows10環境にmediaInfoをインストール行い、pycharmを利用してpymdeiainfoのパッケージをインストールをした上で下記コードを実行しました。

Welcome to pymediainfo’s documentation!
https://pymediainfo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

## 実行コード

```
from pymediainfo import MediaInfo
media_info = MediaInfo.parse('指定の動画ファイルパス')
for track in media_info.tracks:
    if track.track_type == 'Video':
        print track.bit_rate, track.bit_rate_mode, track.codec
```

## エラー文

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ディレクトリパス/script.py", line 110, in <module>
    media_info = MediaInfo.parse(filepath)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymediainfo\__init__.py", line 176, in parse
    lib = cls._get_library(library_file)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymediainfo\__init__.py", line 142, in _get_library
    return windll.MediaInfo
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 421, in __getattr__
    dll = self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 351, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] 指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。

Process finished with exit code 1
```

## 問題点

下記リンクを見てみると、似たような問題の方がいます。
恐らくmediainfo.dllが読み込まれていない事が原因だと思うのですが、対処方法が不明です。
おわかりの方がいれば教えていただきたいです。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36453900/python-pymediainfo-module-error-126-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found

Comment: 記載のリンク先には「Mediainfo.dllの場所をPATHに追加していないからでは」と回答がありますが、これは試しましたか? (エラー内容からするとこの可能性が高いと予想します)

Comment: コメント有難うございます。Mediainfo.dllとそのディレクトリはシステムの環境変数に設定してみましたが、同じエラーが発生します。